# How to rewrite a js file in .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

I want to count the number of requests to a file via a rewrite to a php script. I am using the following code in the .htaccess file for this redirect:

**Option 1:**

```
RewriteEngine On  
RewriteBase / 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} test\.js$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /handler.php?filename=%{REQUEST_FILENAME} [L]
```

**Option 2:**

```
RewriteEngine On  
RewriteBase / 
RewriteRule (.*test\.js$) /handler.php?filename=$1 [L]
```

But this redirection doesn't happen, it outputs the normal contents of the test.js file, without involving the handler.php file

Comment: The files that you want to check are something like slidetest.js, navtest.js,... And you want to redirect all of that to this /handler.php?filename=$1 ?

Comment: Your rules would not perform a _redirect_, but an internal rewrite only. _"it outputs the normal contents of the test.js file, without involving the handler.php file"_ - and how exactly have you verified that?

Comment: @CBroe I checked it by writing the function file_put_contents("status.txt", date("Y-m-d H:i:s").PHP_EOL, FILE_APPEND) in handler.php and it works at normal startup, but it doesn't work at the supposed request via JS

Comment: @hanifzekri yes

Comment: `(.*test\.js$)` - that $ inside the braces makes little sense there, that should come _after_ the capturing group.

Answer (score 0):

this line will do the job for you:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+test\.js)?$ /handler.php?filename=$1 [L,NC,QSA]
```